# Moving the Start menu bar

Tags: gnome-panel

How do I move the start bar on top to the right or left edge of the screen?

Comment: please make us clear what do you mean by start menu bar. Is it the menu/icons on panel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the Gnome 'panel', right click on it and go to 'Properties'. Then change the 'orientation' option.

Note that if you want to move it to the left or right, and are using the default Ubuntu themes, you will probably want to change the background colour to a solid fill for aesthetic purposes.

[image: Panel Properties Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can move the whole bar, by holding the ALT key and dragging (holding the left mouse button) the bar to the side you want it to be.

You can move individual items, by right clicking the item, and then deselecting the last option called 'pin to panel' (or something similar, i'm not sure what the english translation is). After it is no longer pinned, you can move individual items in two ways:

- you can drag them using middle-click (clicking the scrollwheel on your mouse)
- you can right click and select 'move' and then move the item without dragging

Answer (score 1):

The "start menu bar" is called the panel. To change it's orientation, right click on it on the empty part, then select `Properties`. You should see this dialog, which you can select the orientation on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer assuming you just want to move icons.

right_click on icon -> uncheck Lock To Panel -> now you can move the icon.

Answer (score 0):

alt + windows key + right click on bar --> properties